# Avoiding long lines of code in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, newline, backslash

I try and keep my code within 80 characters wide so it is easy to see side by side in a standard window I set up.  In doing this, I have a Python v2.7 construct like this:

```
subseq_id_to_intervals_dict, subseq_id_to_ccid_formats_dict, subseq_id_to_min_max_count_dict = map_cases(opts,
                                            format_to_ccid_funcs,
                                            sys.stdin)
```

So I broke it up like this:

```
subseq_id_to_intervals_dict,
subseq_id_to_ccid_formats_dict,
subseq_id_to_min_max_count_dict = map_cases(opts,
                                            format_to_ccid_funcs,
                                            sys.stdin)
```

But that caused errors

> NameError: name 'subseq_id_to_intervals_dict' is not defined

Until I added backslashes:

```
subseq_id_to_intervals_dict,        \
subseq_id_to_ccid_formats_dict,     \
subseq_id_to_min_max_count_dict = map_cases(opts,
                                            format_to_ccid_funcs,
                                            sys.stdin)
```

Why is it that the comma at the end of the line does not inform Python sufficiently to understand the syntax and not get an error?  Is there a cleaner way to do this without backslashes?

Comment: The preferred way according to PEP8 is to add parens and use the implied line continuation.

Comment: Don't forget that `foo,` is a complete statement (it's a tuple with a single element). You can put parentheses around the LHS like @DavidRobinson has suggested. For that reason, Python would become ambiguous if it allowed you to split a line using commas that way (did you mean a 1 element tuple or should I be processing more?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could put the left side of the assignment into parentheses:

```
(subseq_id_to_intervals_dict,
 subseq_id_to_ccid_formats_dict,
 subseq_id_to_min_max_count_dict) = map_cases(opts,
                                            format_to_ccid_funcs,
                                            sys.stdin)
```

The left side is already a tuple- the parentheses just imply the line continuation. The line

```
subseq_id_to_intervals_dict,
```

doesn't imply a line continuation because it is a complete statement- it's a tuple with a single element.